# Is it possible to overclock an Intel i3-3110m?

Tags: bios, overclocking, intel-core-i3, fsb

Is it possible to overclock an Intel i3-3110m notebook processor? I have searched many forums with Google, but all lead to no answers.

I've tried using [SetFSB](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229010420/http://www13.plala.or.jp/setfsb/) but there are no configurations for my motherboard. In addition, there are no settings for overclocking in the BIOS. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**My specs:**

- **Machine**: HP Pavilion g6-2237us
- **CPU:** Intel i3-3110m
- **MB:** Hewlett-Packard 183F
- **BIOS:** Insyde F.25
- **GPU:** Intel HD Graphics 4000

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS controls as much of the overclocking process as the CPU does, and many motherboards do not allow this.

You did not specify the BIOS or the manufacturer of the computer, but if the computer is a "Big box" brand like Dell the chances that it will support overclocking in the BIOS is pretty close to zero.

If you have looked through the BIOS and the options are not there, then the system will not support overclocking. This is often the case in any budget oriented computer.

---

**EDIT**

Now that we have your model of system and CPU:

Don't ever expect a consumer and low-level machine to offer over clocking options. It costs more for the manufacturer to both build and support.

With that Intel CPU, Intel designates CPUs that can be over clocked with the K designator.

Your CPU model, i3-3110m  does not have the K.

Comment: FYI, I added my specs in the op. Yeah, there are no options to do that in the BIOS.

Comment: @Daniel - Even if you could overclock it.  Its a very bad idea to overclock a mobile CPU.  A mobile CPU already will run hotter then a desktop CPU because of the environment its in.  At the end of the day your only talking about 3-5% performance increase anyways.  The i3 you have isn't exactly a performance beast by itself anyways.

Comment: @Ramhound although that's debatable, the mobile CPUs are sometimes better over clockers than their desktop equivalent because they are built to run cooler and on less power, the environment of being in a laptop is generally less of a good thing. Regardless, overclocking is 99% a pissing contest 99% of the time. There are exceptions of course to all rules.

Comment: @Daniel updated with more precide information for your setup.